# Use Jenkins Job DSL to create / modify Docker Agent Templates

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-docker

On our jenkins server we are providing ~30 Docker Agent Templates for build jobs. I've successfully automated the creation of the build jobs for those images using the Jenkins Job DSL plugin. Now I'm wondering whether I could use the Job DSL plugin (or any other plugin that provides scripting) to automate the configuration of the Docker Agent Templates in the Jenkins Settings:

[image]

Comment: Yes you could use the Jenkins Pipeline plugin for this.

Comment: Any hints on how I could use the pipelines plugin?

Comment: Which plugin provides the Docker Agent templates feature?